# Operand should contain 1 column(s) if-clause

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, select

I do not understand why this query is wrong.  I tried the true and false queries alone and it works, but when I put them in the if-clause it does not. Thanks in advance for help :)

```
SELECT 
IF ( 
    (SELECT useronline FROM wp_livechat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = 1
    , 
    (SELECT *
     FROM wp_livechat
     WHERE id >= (SELECT id 
                  FROM wp_livechat
                  WHERE useronline = 0
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  LIMIT 0, 1)
     AND id <= (SELECT id 
                FROM wp_livechat
                WHERE useronline = 1
                ORDER BY id DESC
                LIMIT 0, 1)
    ),
    (SELECT *
     FROM wp_livechat
     WHERE id >= (SELECT id 
                  FROM wp_livechat
                  WHERE useronline = 0
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  LIMIT 1, 1)
     AND id <= (SELECT id 
                FROM wp_livechat
                WHERE useronline = 0
                ORDER BY id DESC
                LIMIT 0, 1)
    )
);
```

EDIT: This is the table: https://ibb.co/huri6e

And i want to get the messages from the last useronline = 0 to the forelast useronline = 0. And if the last entry is useronline = 1 then i want to retrieve the messages from the last entry with useronline = 1 to the last entry with the useronline = 0.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve in this query ? It looks convoluted. I believe that there is more than one column being used in this. but very hard to track

Comment: in the SELECT clause where you define columns there can only be only value..you are using `SELECT *` in the subqueries which is not possible there.

Comment: But when i run this query alone it works:
SELECT *
FROM wp_livechat
WHERE ID >= (SELECT ID 
FROM wp_livechat
WHERE useronline = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1, 1)
 AND ID <= 
(SELECT ID 
FROM wp_livechat
WHERE useronline = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 1);

Comment: I edited and indented your query.  It help understand what is going on since it is simpler to read and figure out there each query starts and ends.  As for your last comment, you could add this, properly indented, to your question.  Code in comments is hard to read since you cannot format it.  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Learn some SQL syntax before writing long query like this.  Your syntax is not even valid.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this query. Thanks anyways :)

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_livechat
WHERE ID > (
    SELECT IF ( 
    (SELECT useronline FROM wp_livechat ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) = 1,
        (SELECT ID 
        FROM wp_livechat
        WHERE useronline = 0
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1)
    ,
        (SELECT ID 
        FROM wp_livechat
        WHERE useronline = 0
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1)
    )
)
AND ID <= (SELECT ID FROM wp_livechat WHERE useronline = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);
```